# Python 3: Byte issue

Tags: string, python-3.x, byte

So im coding something in python, and i cant seem to find anyfix for this anywhere. so everytime i get something like this:

`\xe2\x9d\xa4`

my code at the moment for printing to the console:

```
log = "Message: " + msg.content + " by " + msg.author.name + " (" + msg.author.id + ") @ " + msg.channel.server.name + " in " + msg.channel.name
print(str(log.encode("utf8")))
```

if your wondering what/where the msg stuff is coming from its a program/chat thing, im getting the information of the message sent, the contents, etc. but for some reason i cant translate those bytes to propper strings/letters etc.

Comment: Please use actual text in your question, not screenshots of text. You can edit your question to remove the screenshots and replace them with the actual text.

Comment: Don't try to encode the string, just print it directly. `print` in Python 3 should do the encoding automatically. If it doesn't, that's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I played a little bit around with your example and found something sweet..

First off: do not use the `str()` to convert from bytes, the result is not what you might expect:

```
>>> str(b'abcd')
"b'abcd'"
```

Python just puts the string representation of the input bytes into some other string.

Convert like this:

```
>>> b'abcd'.decode('utf-8')
'abcd'
```

---

I wrote some simple class to simulate your `msg`:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        [setattr(self, k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()]

msg = Obj(
    content='some text',
    author=Obj(
        id='1337', name='some author'
    ),
    channel=Obj(
        server=Obj(name='localhost'),
        name='#some_channel',
    ),
)
```

Second: Create a log function wich takes the `msg` Object and prints the information:

```
def log_msg(msg):
    content = msg.content
    return '''Message: \
{content} \
by {author_name} ({author_id}) \
@ {server_name} \
in {channel_name}'''.format(
        content=content,
        author_name=msg.author.name,
        author_id=msg.author.id,
        server_name=msg.channel.server.name,
        channel_name=msg.channel.name,
    )
```

It uses a multi-line string `''' ... '''` and [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to construct an output string.

Now I can do:

```
print(log_msg(msg))
>>> Message: some text by some author (1337) @ localhost in #some_channel
```

---

Now, if I use your sample data, something happens:

```
msg.content = '\xe2\x9d\xa4'

print(log_msg(msg))
>>> Message: â¤ by some author (1337) @ localhost in #some_channel
```

Looks weird, but if you look up the codepoints somewhere, everything seems ok:

[\xe2](http://www.codetable.net/hex/e2); [\x9d](http://www.codetable.net/hex/9d); [\xa4](http://www.codetable.net/hex/a4)

---

But this is wrong, as we are dealing with bytes there:

```
msg.content = b'\xe2\x9d\xa4'
print(log_msg(msg))
>>> Message: b'\xe2\x9d\xa4' by some author (1337) @ localhost in #some_channel
```

This is also wrong, we get the string representation of the input bytes here.

Do the conversion before printing, so change the start of the log function:

```
def log_msg(msg):
    content = msg.content
    if not isinstance(content, str):
        content = content.decode('utf-8')
    return '''Message: \
              ...
```

And see this:

```
msg.content = b'\xe2\x9d\xa4'
print(log_msg(msg))
>>> Message: ❤ by some author (1337) @ localhost in #some_channel
```

So, don't confuse the data types (bytes, str) and don't confuse the order of conversion... ❤